# Health hazards of disassembling electronic devices?

Tags: electrical-engineering, consumer-electronics, recycling

I´ve been disassembling a lot of electronic devices in order to recycle them, separating plastics, electronic boards and bolts/other metal parts.

Is there any proof of health hazards for doing it without any kind of protection?

I´m worried about possible substances used when building that could affect me by touching or inhaling them.

Comment: What has Google found for you?  What search terms did you use?  (I would wear gloves, to be sure -- older electronics use tin-lead solder, and lead exposure isn't good).

Comment: Without researching myself, based on experience in other fields, I would suggest the bare minimum personal protective equipment you should wear would be gloves; some form of eye protection, in case something flicks into your eyes or face & a dust mask or respirator if dealing with particular chemicals or molten or vaporized metals, such a remelted solder. Solder is generally a mixture of tin & lead. Be careful to avoid lead poisoning from touching or inhaling lead based fumes or materials.

Comment: Are you using a solder iron for de-soldering

Comment: Thanks for your input! 

1. I found nothing valuable. I looked for it on every way i can think of but without success. I once heard about a video supposedly on YouTube about someone explaining exactly this but couldn´t find it.

2 & 3. As i`m using a solder iron for de-soldering, i´ll specially take the dust mask advice. I didn`t know that solder was a mixture of tin & lead.